# Two unnamed namespaces, defined in the same declarative region

Tags: c++, namespaces, unnamed-namespace

Consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

namespace
{
    int a = 5;
}

namespace
{
    int a = 5;
}
int main()
{ 
    int i=5;
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

This code is invalid. It is because redefinition of `a` is occurred. But I expected that this is valid. Actually, the sec. 3.3.6/1 said:

> [...]The potential scope denoted by an **original-namespace-name** is the
>   concatenation of the declarative regions established by each of the
>   namespace-definitions in the same declarative region with that
>   **original-namespace-name**.[...]

But unnamed namespace definition is not original-namespace-definition and the sec. 7.3.1/1 said:

```
namespace-name:
    original-namespace-name
    namespace-alias
original-namespace-name:
    identifier
```

and

```
original-namespace-definition:
    inline_opt namespace identifier { namespace-body }
```

Moreover, the sec. 7.3.1.1 said:

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by
>
> ```
> inlineopt namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
> using namespace unique ;
> namespace unique { namespace-body }
> ```
>
> where inline appears if and only if it appears in the
>   unnamed-namespace-definition, all occurrences of unique in a
>   translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this
>   identifier **differs from all other identifiers in the entire program**.

This implies that two unnamed namespaces have the different ***unique***.

Can you explain behavior in the code which I cited?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's in the very piece you quote:

> all occurrences of *unique* in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier

So all unnamed namespaces in a translation unit are the same one.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding. Thanks a lot.